# How do I undelete an answer, after editing, that has been deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete

How do I undelete an answer, after editing, that has been deleted by a moderator?

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/168211/36568

[image]

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), in the section *How can I undelete one of my posts?*.